# What scanners are there for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, scanner

Can anyone recommended some scanners for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Are you looking for scanner software or hardware?

Comment: scanners, which works well with ubuntu.  not all of them does

Comment: That'll make the question too broad for AU scope

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping recommendation request.

Comment: All Epson scanners have proprietary drivers for Linux.

Comment: thank you so much about epson.  and I am really sorry if this post was not allowed.  I am truly sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I have a Samsung Xpress M2070W. It is a Monochromatic Laser Printer and Scanner. It perfectly works in Linux Mint 18  with the drivers downloaded directly from Samsung website.

Comment: thanks, but I am only looking for a scanner, not a printer and copier also.  But helpful thank you!